# command center with restricted access to servers

Tags: linux, ansible

I am looking for an automation approach:
I have many linux servers and I want to be able to run some scripts on them without requiring to login to servers via ssh and run the tasks manually,

I want to have a unified command center which can run specific predefined tasks on the servers.

I know that there are several tools such as ansible that satisfy this requirement,

but I have another requirement: I want to restrict the command center to be able to run the predefined tasks and **absolutely** nothing more. so if the command center is fully compromised, the attacker can do nothing more than the predefined tasks, any solution that gives the command center ssh access contradicts this requirement.

I searched and tried some tools but no one fits my needs.

Comment: "any solution that gives the command center ssh access contradicts this requirement" ... You are aware that ssh can restrict which commands can be run, right?

Comment: Yes, but there are some complications: some tasks require root access (such as upgrading all debian packages), hence I should give the command center root user access. as you mentioned the commands could be restricted. In practice sometimes it is required to kill a running job, so it is required to whitelist the kill command for root user which is very dangerous. @muru

Comment: For conditions like these, you shouldn't give direct access to the commands being run, but instead write scripts which do the required tasks and allow access to only those scripts. So one script will do the package upgrading, another script will take PIDs to kill as arguments and only kill those which match some criteria, etc., and then your user will be constrained to run only these scripts using SSH.

Comment: "_I searched and tried some tools but no one fits my needs._", I am afraid such (commercial) tool does not exists yet, but only parts of it. One part of your answer is within the comment of @muru.

Comment: Others parts like "_without requiring to login to servers via SSH_" are partially available, in example via [`sknock`](https://github.com/tumi8/sKnock). Then, others like "_I want to have a unified command center ..._" for such would need to be implemented by youself.

Comment: Thanks @muru "For conditions like these, you shouldn't give direct access to the commands being run ...", It may be a good solution but requires some work ...

Answer (score 0):

As you are finding out, solutions built by other people don't solve the problem you have in your networks that serve your use cases under the requirements/restrictions imposed by your employer/organization.

I.e., you can't just copy a solution from the Internet, paste it into your architecture, and have it work perfectly for you.  You will have to customize it to fit your requirements/needs.

We all go through the process of learning this.  You are learning it, too.  Welcome to the club.

In your case, there are several configuration management suites that can handle the part of your solution that performs the changes/actions on your servers.  Ansible, Chef, Puppet, Saltstack, and others can do this part, usually by means of root access (directly or via sudo).  But while they can each do some regulation of which users are allowed to invoke them, they can't fully satisfy your requirements.

But that layer of regulation (control) can be handled by another software suite, working together with your configuration management system.  For example, you could use a CI/CD platform like Jenkins to invoke Ansible playbooks.  Imagine an architecture where Ansible uses privileged access to accomplish the automated tasks you need, but only the Jenkins worker machines have the privileges to invoke the Ansible playbooks.  The Jenkins configuration controls which users are allowed to run the playbooks.  You get automation tasks that can do the work, and control over who can run which tasks.  The *combination* of Ansible and Jenkins meets all your security and business requirements.

Since this is more like a set of Infrastructure/Operations tasks, you would create a separate Jenkins instance from the one that the software developers use to deploy their custom applications.

Does it have to be Ansible and Jenkins?  No. I suggested them because they're widely used and you probably can visualize using them together.  If you're more familiar with another CI/CD suite or another config management suite, you can use those instead.  The idea I wanted to offer is combining two (or more) software suites as building blocks to create the complete solution that meets all your needs.